# Need help to understand why my CONTAINS returns no results?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I never heard of `CONTAINS` and full text indexing until I read this question - [Is there any way to search for numbers with leading zeros in SQL Server Full-text indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701562/is-there-any-way-to-search-for-numbers-with-leading-zeros-in-sql-server-full-tex)

I tried to create my own sql example for this as shown below. But, my query gives me zero rows. Why ?

Final query -

```
select *
from Philly
where contains(body,'123')
```

SQL to create table so that you can run the above query -

```
USE [MyDb]
GO
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [DummyCatalog]
WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = ON
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Philly](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [body] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Philly] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Philly] ([id], [body]) VALUES (1, N'I  like 000123')
INSERT [dbo].[Philly] ([id], [body]) VALUES (2, N'Hi Five !!!')
```

Then create a full text index on Body using the instructions given here - 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/

Comment: it looks like you forgot to add the "final query" that returns no results.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Make sure you have full-text search feature installed.

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this:

```
select id, body from Philly where contains(body,' "*123" ');
```

I think you need to specify the column names in the select Statement and you have to use the * prefix in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use LIKE instead of contains, but you could use either as long as the table is full-text indexed.

```
select *
from Philly
where contains(body,'123')
```

should work if you have done the following to your table

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Philly KEY INDEX id
```

However I think it is easier to just run

```
select * from Philly where body like '%123%'
```

Which will return any row where body contains 123 anywhere in it proceeded or preceeded by any number of characters.