# finding similar keywords in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to be able to find keywords in my database.

Currently I am using the like wildcard '%keyword%'; however if the database contains text for strawberries, and the keyword is strawberry, then it will return no results.

How can I search for plural and singular words for each result, is this possible without more indepth coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Full-Text Search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) is used for this in SQL Server.

Comment: where FREETEXT ([Long_Desc], 'strawberry') was the answer, I was using Contains.

Comment: but what if I'm searching for 'chicken breast'; then freetext returns everything with just chicken and breast; I'd like to narrow results some.

Comment: I have a related question. Can you please help me ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701818/need-help-to-understand-why-my-contains-returns-no-results

Comment: ok, I just have to split the keywords and search each one seperately

Answer (score 1):

In all mainstream databases there is full text search and indexing. However to find a word spelt slightly differently you either need to consider something like levenshtein distance (there is a Postgres extension for this) or consider stemming, a concept from natural language processing whereby you store the root of the word and ignore the various endings nouns and verbs can take.

I'm not sure what db you are using, but there is a very good article here about fuzzy string searching options in Posgtres: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/158-Where-is-soundex-and-other-warm-and-fuzzy-string-things.html